# How can I add the field name to a localized Required Field validator?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, localization, attributes

When using a Required attribute on a field, the default message is "The *field name* field is required".

Most of the localization examples I've seen have unique resources for each field:

```
  [Display(Name = "Field1", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Test))]
  [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Field1Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Test))]
  public string field1 { get; set; }

  [Display(Name = "Field2", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Test))]
  [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Field2Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Test))]
  public string field2 { get; set; }
```

Is there any way to duplicate the default functionality with a localized resources, so that I could have something like:

```
  [Display(Name = "Field1", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Test))]
  [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "resRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Test))]
  public string field1 { get; set; }

  [Display(Name = "Field2", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Test))]
  [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "resRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Test))]
  public string field2 { get; set; }
```

where resRequired would be something like:  `The {0} field is required.`

Answer (score 1):

Well, it turns out that simply changing my resource value to "The {0} field is required" is all that's needed.

Comment: So simple and somewhat obvious. Other tries like {1}, {2} or {n} - where n is a number different than 0 - will generate an error. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: 4 years later, I apparently helped one person.  Still worth it :)